# CSS: Set an image as background, keep its size unchanged

Tags: css

I'm using a big image as background. However, **it always resize automatically**(Can't display full height of the img), How to deal with it? 
One way is to set its height to the image's height. But when I'm reuse the class for other images, I have to change the height many times.

```
#HTML
div.img-bg
  div.content
#CSS
.img-bg
background-image: .....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it always resize automatically" - it scales when resizing browser's window?

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff My fault. I mean the image cant show its full height(while width is in its size)

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U4Bwv/1/)

Try `background-size: auto;` (the default value)

If you do not resize the background-image and use it's full size, your `div.content` should be as big as the image height.

So, as far as i understood, you set width to `.content`, now you can try to set `height` or `min-height` to fit the background-image's height.

Without height setted, I guess you have something like on the pic.[image]

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U4Bwv/3/)

Comment: There is a `min-height` to set the image's height. How can i get rid of it?

Comment: So, you want to see the whole background image and let it be unscaleable?

Comment: Exactly, just leave it there, do not change its original size at all

Comment: Updated. Check the answer.

Comment: Can I get the full height of the img without setting `min-height`? Or I can only do this by using `<img>` Instead?

Comment: The background will fit the container's size, so, if possible, use either height/min-height or img.